# Permissions required for reading/writing to file

Tags: linux, files, permissions

I am confused about the 2nd part of this question (see photo below). As user and group permissions are contradicting. User doesn't have the execute permission but the group has. Can user also execute as user is the part of the group? or are all permissions are independent of each other?

[image: Assignment question]

> A system has the following ordinary users and groups (and no others):
>
> | User | Groups |
> | --- | --- |
> | alice | staff, users, course |
> | bob | admin, users |
> | carol | admin, users, course |
> | dave | staff, users |
> | eve | course, users |
> | fred | admin, staff, users |
>
> Consider the following directory listing:
>
> ```
> -r-x--xr-- 1 alice course   138856 Apr 27 10:46 file1
> ----rwxr-x 1 dave  staff   2190232 Apr 27 11:49 file2
> ---xr--r-x 1 carol course    24000 Apr 27 09:14 file3.sh
> -rwx-----x 1 fred  admin    123456 Apr 27 11:50 file4.txt
> ```
>
> and the following command output:
>
> ```
> $ file file*
> filel:     ASCII text
> file2:     POSIX shell script, ASCII text executable
> file3.sh:  POSIX shell script, ASCII text executable
> file4.txt: ELF 64-bit ISB executable, ×86-64
> ```
>
> List all of the users who are allowed to do the following.
>
> 1. Read from file1
>
>    Alice, bob, dave, fred (+2)
> 2. Write to file2
>
>    Alice, fred (+1)

Dave is owner who cannot write, but he is also in the group that can write. ????Confused here As far as i understand it, you can only have one set of permissions per person. So since dave is the owner, they are only affected by the 'owner' permissions. Similarly, a group member's permissions are unaffected by what permissions the owner has

Comment: @JaromandaX I think the question is whether `dave` can write or not, and you will find that they can not, even though they are part of the `staff` group.  An answer would explain why this is the case.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 0):

Owner permissions take precedence over group permissions which take precedence over other permissions.

So as `dave` is the owner of `file2`, he will have owner permissions, which are `---`, so he cannot read from or write to the file (or execute it). Whether `dave` is part of group `staff` is irrelevant here.

Note that these examples are for educational purposes only and you are unlikely to encounter file permissions like this in real life. There are simply no practical examples, why group permissions should be more permissive than owner permissions.